# CNN is not learning appropriate, how to know if my dataset is adequate?

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to implement CNN presented in this paper "A Novel Machine Learning Aided Antenna Selection Scheme for MIMO Internet of Things" which is found in [this article](https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/20/8/2250).

In my implementation, I follow all instructions therein, however, my binary-crossentropy loss function is not decreasing, i.e., it is constant over all epochs. I have been trying: change learning rate, normalize data set (min max, standard scale), change the number of epochs/batch_size, change the optimizer however nothing is making effect.

Have anyone any suggestions?

```
matcont = hdf5storage.loadmat('train.mat') 
# matcont = sio.loadmat('train')
Input = (matcont['in'])
Output = (matcont['out'])


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (2, 2), padding="same",input_shape=(1,1,8)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
# model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv2D(16, (2, 2), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
# model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# model.add(Conv2D(16, (2, 2), padding="same"))
# model.add(Activation("relu"))
# model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# model.add(Conv2D(16, (2, 2), padding="same"))
# model.add(Activation("relu"))
# model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# model.add(Conv2D(16, (2, 2), padding="same"))
# model.add(Activation("relu"))
# model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# model.add(Conv2D(16, (2, 2), padding="same"))
# model.add(Activation("relu"))
# model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# model.add(Conv2D(16, (2, 2), padding="same"))
# model.add(Activation("relu"))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(8,activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()
adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, decay=0.01)
model.compile(adam,loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(Input,Output,epochs=100,validation_split=0.11,batch_size=100)
```

[image: looping over epochs]

Answer (score 0):

You first want to verify that your model is able to conquer the data. The way to do that is to focus on minimizing the training loss by dropping regularization and increasing the model size until it overfits the data. The model should be able to get an almost "perfect score" on the training data.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't matter how as big as my model, it always provides 0.75 accuracy.

Comment: You probably want softmax and not sigmoid in the last layer and categorical_crossentropy instead of binary_crossentroy.

Comment: I just follow the article. But if my labels are [0 1], why do I have to utilize categorical_crossentropy?  However, I tried to use sigmoid and categorical_crossentropy and sigmoid, and the val_accuracy has been reduced to 0.04 and val_loss = 4.18.

Comment: Because your model outputs 8-dimensional vectors, doesn't it? What are those 8-dimensional vectors supposed to represent?

Comment: Theses 8-dimensional vectors represent active/non-active antennas, lets suppose that there are 8 antennas and I want to activate 2 (for instance antenna 2 and antenna 6), then the output is: [0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0].

Comment: That is a multi-label classification problem which can be hard to train for. You can try and simplify it into a binary classification problem so that the network outputs 1 if the total number of antennas are greater than say 4 and 0 otherwise. I would also change the batch size, 16 or 32 seem more apt then 100.